# Ensuring dash toward mouse position is always a consistent distance

Tags: unity, c#, physics, rigidbody

I'm making a 2D game where the player character should dash toward the mouse position when the player clicks, but the dash is currently not a consistent distance each time.

Let's say you put the cursor far-right like x = 20, so the character moves 20 units. But if you put it closer, like at  x = 5, the character dashes only 5 units.

How can I limit the position input to just a direction, so the player character would travel the same distance, no matter where the mouse is positioned?

```
void FixedUpdate() {
    //...
    float xor = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), yor = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    if ((xor != 0 || yor != 0) && !dash)
    {
        rg2d.velocity = new Vector2(xor * speed, yor * speed);
        anim.SetFloat("speed", Mathf.Abs(xor + yor));
    }
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0) && !fire)
    {
        //PUNCH
        dash = true;
        fire = true;
        StartCoroutine(Stop_Fire(0.5f));
        anim.SetTrigger("attack");
        fist.GetComponent<Collider2D>().enabled = true;

        Vector2 pos = (transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition)).normalized;

        rg2d.AddForce(-pos * punch_force, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}

// I call this function at the end of the attack animation, in the Animation window
public void Stop_Dash()
{
    dash = false;
    fire = false;
    fist.GetComponent<Collider2D>().enabled = false;
    rg2d.velocity = Vector2.zero;
}
```

Comment: Where do you set `fire` to `true`?

Comment: @DMGregory sorry forgot to include that part. edited it.

Comment: Can you show us how your camera is configured? Orthographic / perspective, and any transformation applied to it?

Comment: I haven't even touched any values in the camera. i added it to post.

Comment: You're taking a 3D vector with a potentially-large z component, normalizing it, then discarding the z to make it a 2D vector. This will result in a vector that can be quite a bit smaller than unit length. Does converting to 2D before normalizing make any difference for your case?

Comment: I think you're right. I'm not sure what I did was the thing you wanted but it worked regardless, thank you.

Comment: Please do not edit your question into a "(SOLVED)" version — this makes it confusing for both our automated systems and for future readers. When you find a solution, the thing to do is to keep the question as-is, and post that solution as an Answer, then Accept that answer (after a short system-imposed delay if accepting your own answer).

Comment: will do but i have to wait 2 days for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

said in the comment section:

> You're taking a 3D vector with a potentially-large z component,
>   normalizing it, then discarding the z to make it a 2D vector. This
>   will result in a vector that can be quite a bit smaller than unit
>   length. Does converting to 2D before normalizing make any difference
>   for your case?

```
        Vector3 mousepos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        Vector3 moveDirection = (transform.position - mousepos);
        moveDirection.z = 0;
        moveDirection.Normalize();

        rg2d.AddForce(-moveDirection * punch_force, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```

Comment: The reason for this is that ScreenToWorldPoint gives you a point at a depth in front of the camera specified by the z component of the argument. Since you give it a 2D argument, the z is zero, so it gives you a point in the same plane as the camera. Your game objects are in front of the camera, so `transform.position - ScreenToWorldPoint` gives you a 3-vector that points diagonally: partly in the xy plane, and partly in the z. If the xy component was short, the z gets most of the length in the normalized vector, leaving a very small xy component after normalizing. Discard the z first to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are already doing the correct thing (getting `.normalized` which in any way will give you a vector of magnitude of 1) and your problem isn't related to how you get the direction. I guess that `Input.GetAxis("Fire1")` is a continuous event and this code is being executed multiple times per SECOND during multiple FRAMES. Thus you are getting a different distance each time, depending on how long you hold the `Fire1` event.

To fix this you can have some kind of a cooldown, or a bool that would restrict firing an event again until it was released.

**Edit 1**

The z position of [Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html) - "position for depth (for example, a camera clipping plane)."

From official example `point = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, cam.nearClipPlane));`. Which would indicate that `cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition));` should disregard z as it's a `0`. Which in turn would give us `new Vector3(x, y, 0f)`, so normalizing it after conversion to `Vector2` shouldn't give a different result. But I may be wrong, indeed this is something I need to research.

**Edit 2**

Seems like `transform.position` is the culprit. `Vector2 pos = (transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition)).normalized;` If this Component's `transform.position` was changed on `z` axis from `0` to any other value, this would create a different `Vector3` each time a position of this `transform` was changed.

Comment: i already tried doing that but it seems it didn't have any effect, I edited the code to show changes, what am i missing.

Comment: @ZozeR when/where do you call `Stop_Fire(float ct)`?

Comment: I was doing changes sorry i missed to include that part. i edited it once again.

Comment: @ZozeR just curious, was the position of object(player) on `z` axis any different from `0`?

Comment: it was 0, i tent to reset each object's transform when I create them. but it seems the problem was caused by the mouse input z-axis, i think.

Comment: It's bugging me, I will test it when I have the opportunity, just to be sure what `ScreenToWorldPoint` returns.